# Checking if Palindrome Program Always Returns True

Tags: javascript

Sorry for the awkward formatting. I wrote this palindrome checking program and can't figure out why it always returns true. The 'word'refers to an intake through html and so does 'reportIfPalindrome'. Values are intaked and displayed so there is no problem with the html. Any help is appreciated

```
const wordBox = document.getElementById('word');

wordBox.addEventListener('input', checkIfPalindrome);

function checkIfPalindrome() {

    const word = wordBox.value;
    const allCaps = word === word.toUpperCase();
    const outsideTrim = allCaps === word.trim();
    let completelyTrimmed = "";
    let individualCharacter = "";

    for(x=0; x<outsideTrim.length; x++)
    {
        individualCharacter = outsideTrim.substring(x, x+1)
        completelyTrimmed+= individualCharacter === " "? "": individualCharacter;
    }

    let reverseString = ""
    for (x=completelyTrimmed.length-1; x>=0; x--){
        reverseString = completelyTrimmed.substring(x, x+1);
    }   

    let result = completelyTrimmed===reverseString;
    document.getElementById('reportIfPalindrome').innerHTML = result;

}
```

Comment: You do things like this a lot `const allCaps = word === word.toUpperCase();`, which tests for equality on the right and then assigns it to your var. Many of your vars end up being booleans. I'm sure this is not what you want. Also, your function doesn't actually *return* anything.

Comment: I got it to work using your advice. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few flaws in your code. First, you are storing booleans for the variables where you seemingly intend to store the capitalized and trimmed words. Secondly, you are not running the loop with the right boundary conditions. See the updated snippet below.

```js
checkIfPalindrome();
function checkIfPalindrome() {

    const word = "aBa";
    const allCaps = word.toUpperCase();
    const outsideTrim = allCaps.trim();
    let completelyTrimmed = "";
    let individualCharacter = "";

    for(x=0; x<outsideTrim.length; x++)
    {
        individualCharacter = outsideTrim.substring(x, x+1)
        completelyTrimmed+= individualCharacter === " "? "": individualCharacter;
    }

    let reverseString = ""
    for (x=completelyTrimmed.length-1; x>=0; x--){
        reverseString = reverseString + completelyTrimmed.substring(x, x+1);
    }   

    let result = completelyTrimmed===reverseString;
    //document.getElementById('reportIfPalindrome').innerHTML = result;
    console.log(result);

}
```